# match string but only output lines below it + not the matched string itself

Tags: awk, grep

I need to find a way to select the lines below a specified string, in this case, the string containing the function `"y"` - but I don't want to select the string `"y"` itself, in case there are multiple lines under each other with `"y"`.

So what I basically want is to select all of the lines containing `"new o"` but I DON'T want to select a "new o" that is right above the string `"y("`, here is what I'm getting at.

I have a file containing this;

```
new o85 = x(-1.3);
y(o85, 12.0, 91.2, 5);
y(o85, 12.0, 91.2, 6);
y(o85, 12.0, 91.2, 7);
new o86 = x(-1.3);
new o87 = x(-1.3);
y(o87, 12.0, 91.2, 9);
new o88 = x(-1.3);
new o89 = x(-1.3);
new o90 = x(-1.3);
y(o90, 12.0, 91.2, 3);
new o91 = x(-1.3);
new o92 = x(-1.3);
new o93 = x(-1.3);
new o94 = x(-1.3);
new o95 = x(-1.3);
new o96 = x(-1.3);
y(o96, 12.0, 91.2, 3);
new o97 = x(-1.3);
new o98 = x(-1.3);
new o99 = x(-1.3);
```

I want to select these specific lines;

```
new o86 = x(-1.3);
new o88 = x(-1.3);
new o89 = x(-1.3);
new o91 = x(-1.3);
new o92 = x(-1.3);
new o93 = x(-1.3);
new o94 = x(-1.3);
new o95 = x(-1.3);
new o97 = x(-1.3);
new o98 = x(-1.3);
new o99 = x(-1.3);
```

How would I go on about doing something like this?
I tried to find duplicate questions but I was not entirely sure what to search for, if it is duplicated, I apologize.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear. `new o86 = x(-1.3);` is right under `y(`, why did you selected that?

Comment: Because it is not directly above `y(`, it has no "connection" to `y(` so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU grep:

```
grep -zoP 'new o.*?(\n|$)(?!y\()'
```

or this:

```
grep -zoP 'new o.*?;(?!\ny\()'
```

GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="\n*y[^)]*);\n*" -F"\n" 'NF>1{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i}' file
new o86 = x(-1.3);
new o88 = x(-1.3);
new o89 = x(-1.3);
new o91 = x(-1.3);
new o92 = x(-1.3);
new o93 = x(-1.3);
new o94 = x(-1.3);
new o95 = x(-1.3);
new o97 = x(-1.3);
new o98 = x(-1.3);
```

For windows carriage return (`\r\n`) ending files:

```
awk -v RS="[\r\n]*y[^)]*);[\r\n]*" -F"[\r\n]+" 'NF>1{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i}'
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, both seem to select all of the lines containing `new o*`, including the ones I don't want included.

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 3.0

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I want - when I run your `awk` solution, it gives me no output at all.

Comment: Okay, I tried your `grep -zoP 'new o.*?(\n|$)(?!y\()'` solution after deleting reduntant strings that were in the file I wanted to search and it seemed to work.

Comment: Windows 10, no, the file is a bit different, in front of every one of those lines is debug information on when it was executed, example; `[01:45:47]`, I just regex'ed these out and I was able to use your grep solution, thanks a bunch.

Comment: @yoranus So the line endings are carriage returns?

Answer (score 0):

If perl can also be an option, try this,

```
perl -0777 -ne ' while ( /y\(.+?\n(?<!=y)((?-s:^new.+?\n)+)(?<!=y)(new.+?\n)(?=y\(|\Z)/mgs ) { print "$1" } '
```

With your inputs

```
$ cat yoranus.txt
new o85 = x(-1.3);
y(o85, 12.0, 91.2, 5);
y(o85, 12.0, 91.2, 6);
y(o85, 12.0, 91.2, 7);
new o86 = x(-1.3);
new o87 = x(-1.3);
y(o87, 12.0, 91.2, 9);
new o88 = x(-1.3);
new o89 = x(-1.3);
new o90 = x(-1.3);
y(o90, 12.0, 91.2, 3);
new o91 = x(-1.3);
new o92 = x(-1.3);
new o93 = x(-1.3);
new o94 = x(-1.3);
new o95 = x(-1.3);
new o96 = x(-1.3);
y(o96, 12.0, 91.2, 3);
new o97 = x(-1.3);
new o98 = x(-1.3);
new o99 = x(-1.3);
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while ( /y\(.+?\n(?<!=y)((?-s:^new.+?\n)+)(?<!=y)(new.+?\n)(?=y\(|\Z)/mgs ) { print "$1" } ' yoranus.txt
new o86 = x(-1.3);
new o88 = x(-1.3);
new o89 = x(-1.3);
new o91 = x(-1.3);
new o92 = x(-1.3);
new o93 = x(-1.3);
new o94 = x(-1.3);
new o95 = x(-1.3);
new o97 = x(-1.3);
new o98 = x(-1.3);
$
```